# Why cannot I read .txt from a file?

Tags: java, io

This is actually driving me crazy. I do not understand why cannot I read a simple .txt file.

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("/Resources/ExternalArchives/tokens.txt");
    try {
        String everything = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
    } finally {
        inputStream.close();
    }
```

As you might have guessed, the file is located inside the project, in a Source folder called Resources. I have tried everything possible and keep getting the same exception.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ExternalArchives\tokens.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Other paths that I have tried...

```
"/Smoothie/Resources/ExternalArchives/tokens.txt"
"/Resources/ExternalArchives/tokens.txt"
"/ExternalArchives/tokens.txt"
"ExternalArchives/tokens.txt"
"tokens.txt"
```

I am using Eclipse IDE Neon.3.

Thank you!

Comment: supply the full path for method or look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java

Comment: Check your file path.

Comment: `ExternalArchives\tokens.txt` != `ExternalArchives/tokens.txt`.

Comment: Path: /Smoothie/Resources/ExternalArchives/tokens.txt

Comment: @Seth Actually it is. You can use `/` as separator and it will work properly regardless of platform.

Comment: What happens if you paste that path to a file explorer?

Comment: Could `\tokens` be being interpreted as `[tab]okens`?

Comment: @SteveSmith I don't think so because he actually uses "/".

Comment: I am not sure if you refer to the location of the file, but I do not understand why this would not work anyway.
Location: C:\Users\blabla\workspace\Smoothie\Resources\ExternalArchives

Comment: What is the absolute path of that file? Can you open it, when you move it to - say "C:\Temp" and you try to open `new FileInputStream("C:\Temp\tokens.txt");` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like:-

`"src/Resources/ExternalArchives/tokens.txt"`

The first `/` in your path means "from the root of the filesystem".  Depending where exactly the Resources folder is (I'm assuming in a folder called "src"), then leaving out the slash will make it relative to where the Java app is running from.

Comment: wow, I feel stupid. The folder was not actually inside the src folder, but removing the initial "/" worked. Thank you very much.